# Reverse regularity of Probability measure

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory

This is Problem 1.8 from Billingsley's Convergence of Probability Measures.

Let $P$ be a probability measure on a metric space $(S,\mathscr{S})$.
When is it true that for each $\epsilon>0$ there exist an open $G$ and a closed $F$ such that $G \subset A \subset F$ and $P(F-G)<\epsilon$?

I can't really think of a general condition under which this holds. I would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: Are you asking for conditions on $S$ and $P$ which make this possible for every Borel set $A$ ?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Yes that is right.

Comment: It is not clear as to what type of condition Billingsley expects. [ My copy of the book does not have this problem!]. One N & S condition is that every Borel set is a continuity set. This means $P(\partial A)=0$ for every Borel set $A$.

Comment: This holds always, provided $\mathcal{S}$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra. Just verify that the family of sets thus approximable includes all closed sets and is closed under complements and countable unions.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker Why do all closed sets belong to this family? I know that we can approximate any closed set $F$ by open sets of the form $F^e = \{x: d(x,y) < e \forall y \in F\}$ from above, but how can we approximate $F$ by open sets from below?

Comment: @nomadicmathematician Oh. Now I see that I did not read the question carefully enough. I confused the open and closed sets in the nesting.